# Configure eslint to check for missing instance attribute?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is there any way to configure eslint to check for missing instance attribute references? This doesn't seem to be a default option, and I can't find an option or plugin that does this, although I'm not sure I'm looking for the right terminology.

I want to catch cases like this, caused by typos or misspellings:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.myvar = 123;
    }
    myfunc() {
        return this.myyar + 1; // eslint should highlight this "this.myyar is not defined"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "class attribute" in JavaScript. There are class methods (attached to the class prototype) and there are instance properties (attached to every instance), declared either in the constructor, or like this:

```js
class MyClass {
    myvar = 123;

    myfunc() {
        return this.myvar + 1; // eslint should highlight this "this.myyar is not defined"
    }
}

const obj = new MyClass;

console.log(obj.myfunc());
```

But your syntax is also totally valid and should not be highlighted by a linter.

Comment: That's a valid point about terminology, but I'm sure you understand the problem I'm trying to solve. The issue isn't whether or not the syntax is valid. Eslint doesn't simply check syntax. Lots of horrible code is syntactically valid. It checks usage, logical consistency, and best practices. An undefined variable is technically correct syntax. The JS interpreter won't crash trying to access an undefined variable. It'll just use undefined as the value.

Comment: Similarly, running my code will produce a NaN result, when the programmer would expect it to produce a 124, but it won't due to a typo. Those types of bugs are the entire point of eslint. In a conventional function, eslint would report that `myyar is undefined`. I'm asking this question because I'm converting old non-object oriented code, which doesn't use the `this.foo = 123` syntax, into classes, and it's essentially hiding a lot of bugs from eslint because it doesn't seem to support the same type of checks against classes.

Comment: I understand the technical limitations. Instance attributes can be dynamically added or removed, whereas variables declared in a function are effectively static, and therefore can be checked with a static code analysis tool like eslint. However, I was hoping to find some way to apply that same analysis to instance attributes, even if it isn't 100% accurate.

Comment: Did you consider using Typescript?